# How to check all links in cypress without stopping in case of an error

Tags: javascript, cypress

So basicly I have to test many many links on many many sites so I want to write a quite general code. In this case its just checking in the main section on purpose.

```
it('check all links in main', () => {

    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get("main").within(() => {
        cy.get("a").each(page => {
            cy.request(page.prop('href'))
        })
    })
});
```

This is checking all links but only as long as there are no errors. I want it to run through the whole page and just log out for every link if it works or not. Its not supposed to stop after the first error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the `failOnStatusCode` option

```js
cy.get("a").each(page => {
  const link = page.prop('href')
  cy.request({
    url: link,
    failOnStatusCode: false  // allow good and bad response to pass into then
  }).then(response => {
    Cypress.log({
      name: link,
      message: response.status
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your request in a `.then()`instance.

```js
it('check all links in main', () => {

    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get("main").within(() => {
        cy.get("a").each(a => {
           cy.get(a).then((page) => {
           cy.request(page.prop('href'), {failOnStatusCode: false})
           cy.request({url: page.prop('href'), failOnStatusCode:false, })
           })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Sadly that doesnt change anything at all

Comment: Then we also have the possibility of adding ```failOnStatusCode: false```to the request. Updated my OP

Comment: Now this is weird. Its still showing the same error, yet it tells me to use the mentioned "failOnStatusCode: false".

```The response we received from your web server was:

  > 404: Not Found

This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx or 3xx.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: failOnStatusCode: false```

Comment: Ok I got one last attempt....updated OP

Comment: This is almost identical to a script with a similar purpose that I have been using successfully for many months now. If this doesn't work I am out of ideas

Comment: Again the same. I dont understand it either. Yet I really appreciate the time that you put into this. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. I will now post my entire script that I am using and that has been running for months. I designed it specifically to keep running after encountering an error (which it does). Maybe you can make something out if it

Comment: There may be <a> tagged to email or javascript for redirect in @DickwadTheGreat web app. You should include those checks so you send a request to those addresses. Gleb has a good crawler blog example including those checks.